# Ionic handle fullscreen in iphone notch

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm trying to add a fullscreen view but the notch area gets a white bar

[image]

page.html

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-slides>
    <ion-slide>
        <div/>
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide>
        <div/>
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide>
        <div/>
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide>
        <div/>
    </ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>
</ion-content>
```

how do I extend the background image to the notch area?

Answer (score 2):

Add preference for staus bar

`<preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="color" />`